# Splitting a php array from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have been working on this for hours on end trying to split the resultant mysql query into their usable variables and I just don't know what I am doing incorrectly.  I no longer get the resource ID# but now all I get is "array" from the variables when I print_r.  I am trying to get the 3 fields from the select statement in their own array and use the values.  I have been pulling my hair out trying to get this to create usable data.  Any help is greatly appreciated as I feel I could spend many, many more hours tinkering and just seem to be on the wrong track.

```
    $Query = "SELECT guardian.Email, child.CFName,  guardian.FName
    FROM child
    INNER JOIN uaccount ON child.ANum = uaccount.ANum
    INNER JOIN guardian ON guardian.ANum = uaccount.ANum
    WHERE uaccount.ANum = '$ANum';";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $test = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
    print_r('this is the test '.$test."<br/>");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($test, MYSQL_BOTH))
    {
        print_r('this is the row '.$row."<br/>");
        foreach($row as $rows)
            {
                $info = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows, MYSQL_BOTH);
                $Email = $info['0'];
                $FName = $info['1'];
                $CFName = $info['2'];

            }
    }
```

Thank you very much for your assistance thus far.  With a combination of everyone's help I have been able to pull the values from the first level of the array with the following code :

```
            $query = "SELECT guardian.Email, guardian.FName, child.CFName
    FROM guardian
    INNER JOIN uaccount ON child.ANum = uaccount.ANum
    INNER JOIN guardian ON guardian.ANum = uaccount.ANum
    WHERE uaccount.ANum = '$ANum';";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $info = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $Email = $info['0'];
    $FName = $info['1'];
    $CFName = $info['2'];
```

However, that is only returning me 1/3rd of the data as each account has 3 guardian email addresses related to it.  Where I should be getting about 2000 rows returned, I am only getting 670.  That is why I was nesting another layer inside the orginal posting and why I was attempting to pull a fetch_assoc from itself.  If you cannot pull an array from itself, how do you "de-nest" so to speak?  Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not how you do `print_r`. Change it to `print_r($rows);` (or `echo '<pre> . print_r($rows, TRUE) . </pre>';`

Comment: print_r($row); and print_r($test); is the correct syntax

Answer (score 1):

```
$emQuery = "SELECT guardian.Email, child.CFName,  guardian.FName
FROM child
INNER JOIN uaccount ON child.ANum = uaccount.ANum
INNER JOIN guardian ON guardian.ANum = uaccount.ANum
WHERE uaccount.ANum = '$ANum'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$Email = array();
$FName = array();
$CFName = array();
$test = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
print_r('this is the test '.$test."<br/>");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($test, MYSQL_BOTH))
{
    echo 'this is the row ';
    print_r($row);
    echo '<br/>';
            //$info = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows, MYSQL_BOTH);
            $Email[] = $info['Email'];
            $FName[] = $info['FName'];
            $CFName[] = $info['CFName'];


}
```

To the best of my understanding this is what you are trying to do.

**Some highlights:**
print_r can only get a reference to a valid php array, no strings included.
mysql_fetch_assoc fetches a line out of a result set referenced by a variable, and then moves the reference to point to the next row.
You cannot call this function on a the result of it self, as it is not valid syntax.

In general, you'll be better off using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions at least, as it is by far more secure, by allowing you to use parameter binding instead of just using use input as part as your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You should just loop through the rows of your result once like so:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // print_r($row); Debug here if you want.
    $Email = $row['Email'];
    $FName = $row['FName'];
    $CFName = $row['CFName'];
}
```

Note: You were providing a second parameter to `mysql_fetch_assoc()` which only takes one parameter (the result from a query). [See the doc here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

`mysql_fetch_array()` takes another parameter that specifies what type of array to return.

Answer (score 0):

Generalized PDO example out of a project of mine (`$sql` would be your `$Query` string):

```
$qry = $pdo->query($sql);
$all=array();
$idx=0;
while($fields=$qry->fetch( 'PDO::FETCH_ASSOC' )){
    $all[key($fields)][$idx]=$fields[key($fields)];
    while(next($fields)!==false){
        $all[key($fields)][$idx]=$fields[key($fields)];
    }
    $idx++;
}
```

The `$all` variable will hold an array which in turn holds an array for each of the columns you've selected.

Like that you can do neat things like `array_combine($all['Email'],$all['Fname'])` and you'd get an array where the key is the `Email` column and the value would consist of the `Fname` column.